# A few questions about advanced Autohotkey uses

Tags: autohotkey

I have been using [this wonderful piece of software](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for some time now, but for just a few basic things. So I'm wondering if the following would be possible:

- to use different set of shortcuts for different applications - so one shortcut performs different actions in different places.
- to make some form of modes for application, where you could use some switch (vim style) and this would change things the shortcat would do
- if it would be possible to place some caption that indicates which mode you are using - little improvement of previous item

I thank everyone for their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 1 seems solved. As to point 2 and 3, here is how you could do it; my code may not be very efficient, but it works:

```
#Persistent                   ;--This needs to come before any
SetTimer, IsActiveTimer, 20   ;--return in the script.
```

---

```
IsActiveTimer:  ;--Below comes what the timer does
if StateIsActive = 1
{
  MouseGetPos, Px, Py   ;--The below creates tooltip when active
  ToolTip, "State is: Active", Px+40, Py+50, 5
}
else
{
ToolTip,,,, 5  ;--Removes tooltip when not active
   }
return
```

---

```
!^#z::   ;--This is the hotkey that toggles the state
         ;--between active and not active.
If StateIsActive = 1
{
StateIsActive := 0
}
else
{
StateIsActive := 1
}
return
```

---

```
!^#a::  ;--Hotkey that types either Zerg or Borg
        ;--depending on active/not active, so that you
        ;--may automatically choose the right party in
        ;--your documents in any potential war
If StateIsActive = 1
{
Sendinput, Zerg
}
Else
{
Sendinput, Borg
}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For different rules for different applications, look into [#ifWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

For example:

```
; Make Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown work in Safari
#ifWinActive ahk_class {1C03B488-D53B-4a81-97F8-754559640193}
^PgUp::Send ^+[
#ifWinActive ahk_class {1C03B488-D53B-4a81-97F8-754559640193}
^PgDn::Send ^+]

#ifWinNotActive ahk_class PuTTY
+Ins::Send ^v
#ifWinNotActive ahk_class PuTTY
+Del::Send ^x
#ifWinNotActive ahk_class PuTTY
^Ins::Send ^c
```

You right click on the AutoHotkey icon and right click Window Spy to figure out the value of the ahk_class.

Modes like in Vi seem to be possible too.  Take a look at [Kommand](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=281279) for example.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the same #IfWin directive before each line. The directive stays in effect until the next #IfWin directive is encountered. (From the [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) page Mikel linked to: *The #IfWin directives are positional: they affect all hotkeys and hotstrings physically beneath them in the script. They are also mutually exclusive; that is, only the most recent one will be in effect.*)

Answer (score 1):

> to make some form of modes for application, where you could use some switch (vim style) and this would change things the shortcat would do

You can make use of the #If statement available in the current distribution of AutoHotkey_L (the one you are expected to download from the site). You can write something like this:

```
#If Winactive("window_name") and (Mode = Mode1)

F1::MsgBox, Mode1
::mode::Mode1

#If Winactive("window_name") and (Mode = Mode2)

F1::MsgBox, Mode2
::mode::Mode2
```

You can put bare #If at the end so as to finish all the conditionals.

What do you mean by ‘a caption’? You can make a small toolbar-like window with the name of the mode or an image and refresh it whenever you change the mode or with the help of a timer that tracks current mode.